# Can a Triac be driven using only positive voltage due to the laws of Q1 and Q4 quadrants?

Tags: arduino, interrupts, triac, dimming, scr

I have a BTA12-600B Triac and an Arduino.

Is it possible I can trigger both positive and negative amplitudes of an AC cycle by suppling only a positive voltage from the Arduino digital pin to the Triac's gate terminal at the right time and moment?

Basically driving the Triac via the Arduino. The Arduino will supply the proper timing positive voltage to the gate pin with reference to a zero cross detection circuit.

It is possible to drive the Triac properly only using the Q1 and Q4 quadrants? Since Q1 and Q4 quadrants can use a positive voltage on it's gate pin?

Comment: https://robotdyn.com/ac-light-dimmer-module-1-channel-3-3v-5v-logic-ac-50-60hz-220v-110v.html

Comment: Thanks, useful link. But I was hoping to design my own PCB implementing this VFD technology which uses custom built Triac driver.

Comment: there is a schematic for the module. it uses BTA16 - 600B. I have Arduino code for Triac control developed with this Triac module

Answer (score 4):

Yes, it's possible and should work OK **but the whole circuit must be considered live**.

Table 3 of the [BTA12 datasheet](https://www.st.com/resource/en/datasheet/bta12.pdf) states that for a "Standard triac" I<sub>GT</sub> is 25 to 50 mA for quadrants I - II - III and 50 to 100 mA for quadrant IV at V<sub>D</sub> = 12 V, R<sub>L</sub> = 30 Ω.
@Spehro says that the -600B is **not** rated for quadrant IV switching. I'd believe him but I can't see it in the datasheet.

A major concern is that you might be considering driving a mains triac directly from the microcontroller and that the it's ground will now be referenced to mains voltage and must be considered live. This in turn means that you must ensure that the whole device including USB port is isolated properly and you can't connect to a laptop, etc., for serial port debugging, etc.

There is really no need to skimp on safety. An opto-triac provides the required level of isolation for, probably, 50c or so. There are plenty of application notes for the MOC series of opto-triacs and plenty of sample circuits on this site.

[image]

*Figure 1. A sample opto-triac control. Image source: [Electronics Tutorials](http://www.electronics-tutorials.ws/power/solid-state-relay.html).*

You'll find more information in the MOC 3020 datasheet.

- Use the MOC 3020 if you want to be able to dim a load using phase-angle control.
- Use the MOC 3041 if you want on-off control at zero-cross to minimise EMI (electro-magnetic interference).

Comment: Thank You for your reply. Yes it does seem the 600B Triac is able to work on all 4 quadrants. Only special Triacs such as 3Q Triacs only functions from I-IV quadrants. Thanks for the dangers involved with the common mains grounding, specially with the USB. I am well aware and careful about it. I will be using homemade optocouplers made from infrared and phototransistor LEDs. The only reason why I would like build the Triac driver circuit from complete scratch is due to pure educational purposes. Like making your own sandwich, if you know what mean :)

Comment: I think you're correct +1. I only saw table 2 for logic level. It's rated for QIV if you don't mind the double gate current. Negative drive is preferable for unipolar gate drive since the current is lower.

Comment: How would it be possible to drive the Triac using an optocoupler and making a custom made circuit? There will be two optocouplers, one for the zero cross detection and another for the firing of the Triac.

Comment: See the update.

Comment: Thank You for the schematic, is it possible you have a schematic for building an actual component of a "MOC 3020"?

Comment: The MOC 3020 **is** a component. Did you look for the datasheet?

Comment: Thanks for replying, what I meant as building the circuitry from scratch of raw parts to implement the MOC 3020 component. I have infrared/phototransistor LEDs and also a Diac, was wondering if I can uses these basic raw materials and build a component such as the MOC3020.

Comment: Help me build one, I'll buy you lunch.

Comment: The essential component is the light activated triac. I have opened metal can BC108 transistors to make a photo-transistor and stuck an LED into it when I was stuck for a low-voltage opto-isolator. You could try doing the same with a triac but most are TO220 style so I can't imagine that you could expose the die without destroying the bonding wires. The opto-triac can switch AC mains voltages. Your phototransistor can't.

Comment: Thanks for replying, I Have a full blown mini lab with a Rigol oscilloscope and function generator, many transistor types of PNP and NPN, different types of diodes, different types of Triacs. So basically I can't build or implement my own opto-triac? I wasn't expecting to do weird things like cut open a transistor and stick an LED lol

Comment: that's why they make opto-triacs! As mentioned, if you want to make your own, then you need to do weird things. I would've suggested carefully removing the epoxy case of a triac and a led. If you were local to me, I could give you a bucket of opto-triacs, otherwise search what you can buy in your market or harvest them from the control boards of white goods (washing machines, etc).

Comment: Another thought is using a pulse transformer. You can wind this yourself.

Comment: Is it not possible to build a Triac driver from couple of transistors, diodes and infrared/phototransistor LEDs?